# Intellij IDEA won't pick up AVD from android studio when using flutter

Tags: android, intellij-idea, flutter, android-virtual-device

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA in conjunction with android AVD to use the new software platform flutter. I've gone through the download youtube videos and it just won't pick up the emulator. Only thing I could think was the issue was that the emulator is saving in C:\ and not in E:\ where I've saved all my android studio related downloads, IntelliJ IDEA, flutter etc. The issue is I don't know how to reroute where to save the AVD? or if that is even the issue? I'm running windows 10 pro.. thanks

Comment: I just open it normally through android studio it loads up fine then jump over to IntelliJ to start a project and it just doesn't pick it up. When I run flutter doctor it just comes up with this error log for connected device "[!] Connected Device"

Comment: emulator is started but intellij IDEA which uses the flutter plug in is suppose to detect the emulator but its not for me for some reason?

Comment: sorry im still a bit of a novice, im not too familiar with command prompts or what youre saying

Comment: C:\Users\H\IdeaProjects\my_flutter_sandbox>adb devices
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I have the SDK tools package, the emulator isn't the issue, its using it in conjunction with IntelliJ IDEA community with the flutter plug in

Comment: i don't think this is getting me anywhere just yet, but do appreciate your help